# How to use existing android app as cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova, phonegap

I have build an `android` app  with help of `quasar` and `cordova`.

Now I want to add print function that is actually device specific (e.g. [mpos device](https://www.famoco.com/android-devices/mobile-point-of-sale/px400/)).

I have uploaded the source code of `native android` project that i want to use in my cordova project [repo of android source code](https://github.com/fahada305/printDev).

I want to call `printText` function into `cordova-plugin` from `native android` 
[link to printText function](https://github.com/fahada305/printDev/blob/8dc1e3ef57545fb09a1c779f60595a6777d454ab/app/src/main/java/com/xact/t1printer/PrintDevActivity.java#L179)

something similar like below:

```
exports.print= function (arg0, success, error) {
  exec(success, error, 'PrintDevActivity', 'printText', [arg0]);
}
```

I need help in these two things:

1. how many files i need to copy from above repo of android project to my cordova plugin
2. what changes i need to do in cordova plugin `plugin.xml` so it will work.

I am confused , should i need to copy only `.java` files or also gradle etc.

This is my `plugin.xml` file of cordova plugin

[image: plugin.xml]

Any help or suggestion will highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question, I think you need to build `cordova plugin` for any `android sdk`.
Please check below link, i think this is have lot of information about building `cordova` plugin with any existing `sdk` or code.

[building-a-cordova-plugin-for-your-native-sdk](https://medium.com/hypertrack/building-a-cordova-plugin-for-your-native-sdk-174f1d7d20ca)

I hope this will help you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

follow this guide [Upgrading Android Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/upgrade.html) and it'll help you in part 1 of updating your config.xml file. Their Documentation is pretty simple to follow along.